# wpa_supplicant and moving between static and dhcp networks

Tags: networking, network-interface, wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to make my raspberry pi move between multiple access points, some using DHCP other are static. I read that using `id_str` in your wpa_supplicant networks and having the corresponding configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` can automatically configure the interface but doesn't look like it's the case in my system.

**/etc/network/interfaces :**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet6 auto

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
#iface default inet dhcp

iface test inet static
address 192.168.0.2
gateway 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

**/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf**

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
    ssid="Skynet Defence Network"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    proto=WPA2
    psk="illbeback"
    priority=10
    id_str="test"
}
```

with this configuration wpa_supplicant connects to the network but the network settings are not set. am i doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have a 1:1 relationship between a supplicant entry AND a network interface like explained here:

- [How to setup multiple WiFi networks?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11631/how-to-setup-multiple-wifi-networks)
- [Jessie or later - How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address/37921#37921)

What I see is that you have a `wlan0` interface with dhcp and static at the same time, and that is not going to happen. If you have multiple access points on the same network(essid), and just some of them with a dhcp available you have a problem with your network layout/project, not with Debian neither `/etc/network/interfaces`.